# Heterogeneous collection as a member of a class in Rust

Tags: rust, hashmap, lifetime, heterogeneous

I am new to Rust, and does not fully understand lifetime, so probably, that is why I can't solv the following issue. I need a solution in which a class has a heterogeneous `HashMap` containing different objects derived from the same trait.

I have to be able to extend an object with some (multiple) functionality dinamically. Other solutions are also welcome. Adding functionality to the class in compile time could also work, but adding functionality directly to the main class not.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait DoerTrait {
    fn do_something( & self, a : u8, b : u8 ) -> u8;
}

struct MyDoer<'a> {
}

impl DoerTrait for MyDoer<'a> {
    fn do_something( & self, a : u8, b : u8 ) -> u8 {
        return a + b;
    }
}

struct MyMain<'a> {
    doers : HashMap<u8,&'a dyn DoerTrait>,
}

impl<'a> MyMain<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            doers : HashMap::new()
        }
    }

    fn add_doer( &mut self, id : u8, doer : & dyn DoerTrait ) {
        self.doers.insert( id, doer );
    }

    fn do_something( & self, id : u8 ) {
        match self.doers.get( &id ) {
            Some( doer ) => {
                println!( "{}", doer(19,26) );
            }
            None => {
                println!( "Doer not specified!" );
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut mymain = MyMain::new();
    let mydoer = MyDoer{};
    mymain.add_doer( 42, &mydoer );
    mymain.do_something( 42 );
}
```

Comment: Your question refers to a problem you're having, but you never describe this problem. What is it?

Comment: I thought that it can be derived from the code. However. I have to be able to extend the main object with some functionality dinamically. Othoer solutions are also welcome, but dynamic functionality change would be important. Actually, changing functionality compile time is also ok, but changing the original class not.

Comment: The point of SO is to document problems and their solutions, so having the problem in the question itself makes it more easily discoverable by others having the same problem. The problem being derivable from the code helps _you_ but not _others._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too sure what issue you have, once `MyDoer` has been stripped of its incorrect (unnecessary) lifetime and the lifetime has correctly been declared on `impl MyMain`, the compiler directly points to the parameter of `add_doer` not matching (after which it points out that `doer` in `do_something` is not a function):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait DoerTrait {
    fn do_something(&self, a: u8, b: u8) -> u8;
}

struct MyDoer;

impl DoerTrait for MyDoer {
    fn do_something(&self, a: u8, b: u8) -> u8 {
        return a + b;
    }
}

struct MyMain<'a> {
    doers: HashMap<u8, &'a dyn DoerTrait>,
}

impl<'a> MyMain<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            doers: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add_doer(&mut self, id: u8, doer: &'a dyn DoerTrait) {
        self.doers.insert(id, doer);
    }

    fn do_something(&self, id: u8) {
        match self.doers.get(&id) {
            Some(doer) => {
                println!("{}", doer.do_something(19, 26));
            }
            None => {
                println!("Doer not specified!");
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut mymain = MyMain::new();
    let mydoer = MyDoer {};
    mymain.add_doer(42, &mydoer);
    mymain.do_something(42);
}
```